# How to change value of global variable within a function with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

now i want to make a web program that when i press keyboard , i change the value of global variable to 1 , if not it is set to 0 . But somehow i cannot change with addEventlistener
This is my code:

```
<script>
var count;
function down(e) {
    console.log("down");
    count = 1 ;
    // body...
}

function up(e) {
    console.log("up");
    count = 0;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", down);
window.addEventListener("keyup", up);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;
//somehow the output is always undefined instead of 1 or 0 , even though the 
//function is executed
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. You need to initialize your variable and update the DOM on the down /up event. http://jsbin.com/ninigax/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Your `innerHTML` assignment is being done before either of the event handlers run. Why would you expect `count` to be incremented?

Comment: yeah but the global variable seem not change at all ,it is still undefined , i want to change to global variable because i want to pass this to Nodejs and use it as an input for my project

Comment: how to set event handlers run all the time and update information to my innerHTML Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already almost there. You just need to do two things:

- Give `count` a default value. When the page loads, probably no keys are being held down, so 0 is a good choice.
- Update the DOM each time the event happens. So you need to call `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count` inside both event listeners.

Once you've done that, it should update how you want:

```js
// Give count a default value.
var count = 0;

function down(e) {
    console.log("down");
    count = 1;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;
    // body...
}

function up(e) {
    console.log("up");
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", down);
window.addEventListener("keyup", up);

// The html won't update automatically, so we have to manually update it each
// time the count is changed. Hence this line is duplicated in both event listeners.
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to update dom when event changes. Below solution will work for you.

```
function down(e) {
    console.log("down");
    count = 1 ;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;

    // body...
}

function up(e) {
    console.log("up");
    count = 0;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = count;

}
```

Comment: Thank you guy , now i understand it